# Django: sub-fields within a model field

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7

In my primary class model Deals, I have certain fields as description, price, date_created etc. I now have to add some fields having sub-fields to it. For eg, I'm trying to add an age field to Deals. This age field further has subfields (like score_for_kid, score_for_baby, score_for_old etc), and I want to edit these scores from the admin.

Here is my models.py:

```
class Deals(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    url = models.URLField(verify_exists=False)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    kid_score = models.IntegerField(max_length=2,default=0)
    teenager_score = models.IntegerField(max_length=2,default=0)
    youth_score = models.IntegerField(max_length=2,default=0)
    old_score = models.IntegerField(max_length=2,default=0)
```

I don't want to store all these sub fields (around 20-25 in 4 different fields) in the model, instead an age field connected to these subfields. Would a ManyToManyField work for this?

The underlying requirement is that when a user selects a subfield (say kids) on the browser, all the objects having higher kid scores are displayed.

I'm very new to Django and any help on this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly ou need to use ForeignKey fields.

```
class Deals(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    #...
    age = models.ForeignKey(Age)

class Age(models.Model):
    kid_score = models.IntegerField(max_length=2,default=0)
    teenager_score = models.IntegerField(max_length=2,default=0)
    #...
```

Have a good read of the [docs on Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/). You might also find it useful to do some reading on relational databases / basic sql.

When you come to edit your objects in the django admin, you'll probably want to use an [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) class.

UPDATE

re-reading your question, it sounds like you might simply want to show / hide these additional fields on the main Deal model. If this is the case then you want to use fieldsets in the admin, with a class 'collapse'. There's an example in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets).

If you want each `Deal` record to have multiple `kid_score`'s associated with it then you want a foreign key. If each `Deal` can only have one `kid_score` then you need to keep the `kid_score` (and other) fields in the main model (if this is confusing then definitely do some reading on sql / relational databases).

Comment: Thanks Aidan, I actually want to have only one kid_score(and other scores) for each Deal, but then I thought having 25 fields for this would make my model too complex. In the code above, I just have 4 fields like this, but I have many more (for different fields). I'm not sure why keeping all these 25 fields in my model would be better instead of having foreignkeys for age etc.

Also, putting 'age = models.ForeignKey(Deals)' in my Age model class works better for me. Thanks a lot for the concept though, it was pretty smooth once I got it.

Comment: If that's the case then you really need to keep everything on the one model. Whilst you could create a OneToOne field, I don't think this is the right solution given that all your deal objects will have scores. You just need to show hide the fields in your html. This isn't too difficult to do with ModelForms / Django Admin.

Comment: Yes I agree, since each Deal object has only one kid_score etc, its better to put that field in the Deal model. However, as I told you, I have many such fields (6 for age, 10 for relationship etc) that may total upto more than 30 such fields. Wouldn't a model with 30-40 fields make running a query or other complex operations slow? Is there a better way to do that and to make it faster?

Comment: No that's the fastest way, multiple tables (models) will be slower than one table with lots of fields. However you might find it helpfull to do some reading on "normalization". It's a standard process for designing relational databases, and might help you if you're really keen to split your data into seperate tables.